# Remove occurrences of substring recursively

Tags: string, algorithm, substring

Here's a problem:

> Given string A and a substring B, remove the first occurence of substring B in string A till it is possible to do so. Note that removing a substring, can further create a new same substring. Ex. removing 'hell' from 'hehelllloworld' once would yield 'helloworld' which after removing once more would become 'oworld', the desired string.

Write a program for the above for input constraints of length 10^6 for A, and length 100 for B.

This question was asked to me in an interview, I gave them a simple algorithm to solve it that was to do exactly what the statement was and remove it iteratievly(to decresae over head calls), I later came to know there's a better solution for it that's much faster what would it be ? I've thought of a few optimizations but it's still not as fast as the fastest soln for the problem(acc. the company), so can anyone tell me of a faster way to solve the problem ?

P.S> I know of stackoverflow rules and that having code is better, but for this problem, I don't think that having code would be in any way beneficial...

Comment: hard to know if our code is faster than yours if you haven't posted yours.

Comment: @cphlewis, of course we can. he explained his approach, and from that explanation the complexity of it is obvious. you either suggest an algorithm with better complexity or not.

Comment: @cphlewis Testing code is a rather limited way of assessing algorithmic performance because (a) you can't possible cover all possible inputs and (b) there will always be constant factor differences due to implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach has a pretty bad complexity. In a very bad case the string `a` will be `aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb`, and the string `b` will be `ab`, in which case you will need `O(|a|)` searches, each taking `O(|a| + |b|)` (assuming using some sophisticated search algorithm), resulting in a total complexity of `O(|a|^2 + |a| * |b|)`, which with their constraints is years.

For their constraints a good complexity to aim for would be `O(|a| * |b|)`, which is around 100 million operations, will finish in subsecond. Here's one way to approach it. For each position `i` in the string `a` let's compute the largest length `n_i`, such that the `a[i - n_i : i] = b[0 : n_i]` (in other words, the longest suffix of `a` at that position which is a prefix of `b`). We can compute it in `O(|a| + |b|)` by using [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm.

After we have `n_i` computed, finding the first occurrence of `b` in `a` is just a matter of finding the first `n_i` that is equal to `|b|`. This will be the right end of one of the occurrences of `b` in `a`.

Finally, we will need to modify Knuth-Morris-Pratt slightly. We will be logically removing occurrences of `b` as soon as we compute an `n_i` that is equal to `|b|`. To account for the fact that some letters were removed from `a` we will rely on the fact that Knuth-Morris-Pratt only relies on the last value of `n_i` (and those computed for `b`), and the current letter of `a`, so we just need a fast way of retrieving the last value of `n_i` after we logically remove an occurrence of `b`. That can be done with a deque, that stores all the valid values of `n_i`. Each value will be pushed into the deque once, and popped from it once, so that complexity of maintaining it is `O(|a|)`, while the complexity of the Knuth-Morris-Pratt is `O(|a| + |b|)`, resulting in `O(|a| + |b|)` total complexity.

Here's a C++ implementation. It could have some off-by-one errors, but it works on your sample, and it flies for the worst case that I described at the beginning.

```cpp
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;

    size_t blen = b.size();

    // make a = b$a
    a = b + "$" + a;

    vector<size_t> n(a.size()); // array for knuth-morris-pratt
    vector<bool> removals(a.size()); // positions of right ends at which we remove `b`s

    deque<size_t> lastN;
    n[0] = 0;

    // For the first blen + 1 iterations just do vanilla knuth-morris-pratt
    for (size_t i = 1; i < blen + 1; ++ i) {
        size_t z = n[i - 1];
        while (z && a[i] != a[z]) {
            z = n[z - 1];
        }
        if (a[i] != a[z]) n[i] = 0;
        else n[i] = z + 1;

        lastN.push_back(n[i]);
    }

    // For the remaining iterations some characters could have been logically
    //     removed from `a`, so use lastN to get last value of n instaed
    //     of actually getting it from `n[i - 1]`
    for (size_t i = blen + 1; i < a.size(); ++ i) {
        size_t z = lastN.back();
        while (z && a[i] != a[z]) {
            z = n[z - 1];
        }
        if (a[i] != a[z]) n[i] = 0;
        else n[i] = z + 1;

        if (n[i] == blen) // found a match
        {
            removals[i] = true;

            // kill last |b| - 1 `n_i`s
            for (size_t j = 0; j < blen - 1; ++ j) {
                lastN.pop_back();
            }
        }
        else {
            lastN.push_back(n[i]);
        }
    }

    string ret;
    size_t toRemove = 0;
    for (size_t pos = a.size() - 1; a[pos] != '$'; -- pos) {
        if (removals[pos]) toRemove += blen;
        if (toRemove) -- toRemove;
        else ret.push_back(a[pos]);
    }
    reverse(ret.begin(), ret.end());

    cout << ret << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
[in] hehelllloworld
[in] hell
[out] oworld
```

```
[in] abababc
[in] ababc
[out] ab
```

```
[in] caaaaa ... aaaaaabbbbbb ... bbbbc
[in] ab
[out] cc
```