# What are efficient ways to delete recursively all occurrences of a substring in a string?

Tags: string, algorithm

Sorry for my bad English.

I have a problem like that. Given a string(maybe a very long string) and a pattern, how can I remove all occurrences of pattern in string? Notice that new occurrence may be appeared after deleting previous one. For example:

```
string: deaabcbcef
pattern: abc
result: deef
```

Are there any algorithms or efficient ways to solve it(within a few second)?

P/S: I make an easy example to make it clear, but I think it's not the way. Length of string can be reached to 10^6 characters, and time limit is 2 seconds. Is there any algorithm for that?

Comment: Within a few seconds? For the string "deaabcbcef", you could do it the naïve way within a few microseconds...

Comment: Note that left-to-right deletion is different from right-to-left deletion. For example, string: abcdcdc, pattern: cdc, you could get result as 'abdc' (left-to-right) or 'abcd' (right-to-left).

Comment: related: [Remove occurences of substring recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28643004/4279)

Answer (score 1):

For *python*, I don't know if there's a *better* way than a simple old-fashioned loop:

```
new = old.replace(pattern, '')
while new != old:
    old = new
    new = old.replace(pattern, '')
```

example:

```
>>> old = 'deaabcbcef'
>>> pattern = 'abc'
>>> new = old.replace(pattern, '')
>>> while new != old:
...     old = new
...     new = old.replace(pattern, '')
... 
>>> new
'deef'
```

Comment: If you have a gigabyte of prefix before the occurrences, it could be better to save the index to start looking. I don't know what "maybe a very long string" means, but repeatedly searching through stuff you know doesn't contain any occurrences could be wasteful enough to matter.

Comment: It is `O(n**2)` algorithm. It may take more than an hour for `old='a'*n+'b'*n, pattern='ab'` and `n=10**6`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- Admittedly there are pathologically bad cases here... Under most normal circumstances I'd expect to only iterate through once or twice.  If there are more pathological cases, I'd probably use a `bytearray` so that the "string" could be mutated in place -- but before coding that up (it'd be a mess), I'd need to know that it was worth my time :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let a string *H* (for *Haystack*) in which we are looking to recursively erase every occurrence of string *N* (for *Needle*). The procedure I will describe performs a *left-to-right* deletion of the pattern.

### Main idea

The first thing to do is to locate every non-overlapping occurrence of *N* in *H*. You can do this in O(|*N*| + |*H*|) using the [*Z-algorithm*](http://ivanyu.me/blog/2013/10/15/z-algorithm/). Let *S<sub>1</sub>,..., S<sub>k</sub>* these occurrences.

Initially, each *S<sub>i</sub>* has a starting position (its index in the original string) and an ending position. We will keep track of these positions. Let *b(i)* and *e(i)* be these positions.

Removing a *S<sub>i</sub>* may yield another match for the needle string. It may do so only if there are some characters before. Here, we are only interested in the window **(1)**:

> *W(i)* = *L(i)* U *R(i)*, with:
>   *L(i)* = [*e(i) - |N| + 1, e(i)-1*]
>   *R(i)* = [*s(i)+1, s(i) + |N| - 1*]

Using the computed values from the Z-algorithm, we can explore the "left" part of the window.

> **Z-property:** The *Z-value* at position *e(i) - k* must be *at least k* for a match to exist.

Thus if there is no index in the left window satisfying this criterion, we are done for *S<sub>i</sub>*. Otherwise, we build a new *Z-array* for *W(i)*. There can only be one non-overlapping match for *N* in *W(i)*. We will always take the *"leftmost"*.

This match will have a new starting position *b(i)* (in *L(i)*) and an updated ending position *e(i)* in *R(i)*. Similarly, we update *L(i)* and *R(i)* to account for the match using the equations in **(1)** with the new *b(i)* and *e(i)*. The recursion goes on until there is no character left in *L(i)* or no character in *L(i)* satisfies the *Z property*.

The idea is to process each *S<sub>i</sub>* using the recursive approach shown above. We will process them from the *leftmost* match (*i = 0*) to the *rightmost*.

***Note that the left window of a given match i may overlap with some removed characters for another matches < i... See the following section to get a solution to that problem.***

After each *S<sub>i</sub>* has been processed, you have a collection of windows defining the removed characters. You process the *W(i)* in that fashion:

1. Let *s = 0*, *e = |H| - 1*
2. For *i=0..n<sub>match</sub> - 1*:

   1. *e = L(i)[|L(i)|-1]*
   2. Copy *H[s..e]* to *O*
   3. *s = R(i)[0]*, *e = |H| - 1*
3. Copy *H[s..e]*

After this procedure, *O* is the output string you are looking for!

### Resolving the "erased index" issue

A problem may occur to define the windows when processing *S<sub>i</sub>* for any *i > 1*. Indeed, *e(i) - k* may fall on an "erased" index for a given *k*.

To resolve that issue, you can build a mapping array between the windows and the *actual* positions in the original string. To compute these values, you may have to loop through the windows of the *S<sub>j</sub>*, *j < i*.

Initially, set *L(i)[k] = e(i) - |N| + 1 + k* for *k = 0..|N|-2*.
For a given index *m* such that *L(i)[m] = t = e(i) - k*:

While (i > 0 and *t* )

1. If *δ = t - R(i-1)[0] < 0*:

   1. If *|δ| > |L(i-1)|*:

      1. Let *δ = δ - |L(i-1)|* and *t = L(i-1)[0] - δ*.
      2. i = i-1, proceed to next loop iteration
   2. Else, let *L(i)[m] = L(i-1)[|L(i-1) + δ]* and exit
2. Else exit

If *t* is negative, then the character does not exist. Furthermore, we now that the abs(*t*) - 1 next characters won't exist either and can thus proceed with *m* + abs(*t*) instead of *m + 1*. In the end, we only keep the existing characters in the window.

Likewise, if *δ < 0*, then we know that the next *|δ| - 2* characters will have the indexes ranging from *L(i)[|L(i)| + δ + 1]* to *L(i)[|L(i)| -1]*.

### Complexity analysis

The initial run of the *Z-algorithm* is *O(|H| + |N|)*. The processing of each match include the maintenance of the windows and the actual searches for subsequent pattern matches.

The search is *O(|N|)* since the windows define a string of *at most* *2.|N|-2* characters.

The maintenance of the windows is a tad more difficult to analyze. But in the end it should be at most *n<sub>match</sub> .|N|* if we skip unnecessary computations using the remarks I made earlier.

In the end, you have an upper bound of ***O(|H| + n<sub>match</sub>².|N|)***.

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanation. I'll try this. Anyway, I would be more appreciated if you give me some code. But thank you very much.

Comment: @user1680791 I don't see where you're asking for code in your question. Furthermore, there's not even a language tag...

Answer (score 0):

Python:

## code:

```
import string
input="salsa"
output = string.replace(input,"sa", "re")
print output
```

## Output:

> relre