# repeatedly remove occurrences of substring until main string is empty

Tags: python, regex, string, algorithm, substring

So I have the stack and needle:

`stack = 'lllolollololollllolol'`

`needle = 'lol'`

If I remove one `needle` from `stack` each time, with the right order, `stack` can be cleared so it's empty at the end.
For example, each time, the `lol` in bold is removed (notice that another `needle` can be further created after the removal):

lllolollolololll**lol**ol

lllolollolololl**lol**

lllolol**lol**ololl

llollolo**lol**l

llol**lol**ol

l**lol**ol

**lol**

*clear*

To find a route like above, the only way I came up with using Python is to use regex (finditer) to find all the `needles` in the `stack`, and use recursion to explore all the possible removing combinations to find the ones that can make `stack` empty. But I know that this is not efficient at all.

Is there a more efficient way to find at least 1 way to remove `needle` to empty `stack` using Python?

I found this topic:
[Remove occurences of substring recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643004/remove-occurences-of-substring-recursively)
But I'm not sure if it 100% apply to my case.

Thanks!

Below is the code I came up with (bad complexity I know..):

```
def answer(chunk, word):
    if chunk.find(word) != -1:
        occ = [m.start() for m in finditer('(?='+word+')', chunk)]
        for o in occ:
            new = chunk[:o] + chunk[o + len(word):]
            answer(new, word)
    else:
        result.append(chunk)
        result.sort()
        return chunk
...
#So all the shortest "leftover stack" after the removal are stored in list 
#"result". These include empty or non-empty outputs depending on how 
#the removal was executed.
```

Comment: Since SO is not a code writing service,If you want to make it a good question pls add your code.

Comment: haha, yeah I'd probably say the same thing if I saw a question like this. I did write my code. And it was part of my foo.bar challenge solution (submitted). I didn't post the code because I wasn't sure if one is supposed to. But I will update my question with the essential part.

Answer (score 3):

As a more general way for solving such tasks you can use a [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) algorithm.

You can start by finding all the `needle`s and start by choosing between them and just remove the choices which will encounter with a critical state in those next state.and continue to check other `needle`s.

Answer (score 3):

You can recurse:

```
import re

def find_all(bigstr, smallstr):
    return [m.start() for m in re.finditer(smallstr, bigstr)]

def removeNeedle(stack, needle, prev):
    if len(stack) == 0:
        print prev
    indices = find_all(stack, needle)
    for index in indices:
        newStack = stack[:index] + stack[index+3:]
        newPrev = list(prev)
        newPrev.append(index)
        removeNeedle(newStack, needle, newPrev)

stack = 'lllolollololollllolol'
needle = 'lol'

removeNeedle(stack, needle, [])
```

This will find *all* such possible solutions. Some of the possible results are following:

```
[2, 1, 5, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 5, 1, 4, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 5, 1, 4, 3, 0]
[2, 1, 5, 7, 1, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 5, 7, 1, 3, 0]
[2, 1, 5, 7, 6, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 10, 5, 1, 0, 0]
[2, 1, 10, 5, 1, 3, 0]
[2, 1, 10, 5, 6, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 10, 9, 5, 1, 0]
[2, 4, 5, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[2, 4, 5, 1, 4, 0, 0]
[2, 4, 5, 1, 4, 3, 0]
[2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 0, 0]
[2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 3, 0]
[2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 1, 0]
```

You can visualize them using:

```
def visualize(stack, prev):
    for p in prev:
        print stack
        print ' ' * p + '---'
        stack = stack[:p] + stack[p+3:]

visualize(stack, [2, 1, 5, 1, 0, 1, 0]) # one of the results
```

Gives you:

```
lllolollololollllolol
  ---
llollololollllolol
 ---
llololollllolol
     ---
llololllolol
 ---
lolllolol
---
llolol
 ---
lol
---
```

**PS:** This method has an exponential time complexity in the length of `stack`.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a loop to remove the substrings

```
stack = 'lllolollololollllolol'
needle = 'lol'

while needle in stack:
    stack = stack.replace(needle, '')

print stack
```

Comment: 2 downvotes without any comment??

Comment: This will replace with only the first occurence, it may or may not give you the correct result. See backtracking algorithms.

Comment: For example, it will not work with this example: `stack= 'lololl'`, `needle='lol'`.